# A domain redirection loop on Laravel Forge, Nginx and SSL when redirecting from non-www domain to the www one

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-forge

I have an HTTPS set up with Let’s Encrypt on Laravel Forge, and I redirect non-secure domain to a secure one using a Laravel middleware:

```
if ( env('APP_ENV') === 'production' ) {
    $request->setTrustedProxies([$request->getClientIp()]);

    if ( !$request->secure() ) {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }
}

return $next($request);
```

Here’s my `example.com` (not an actual domain) Nginx configuration:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/120143/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/120143/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '[...]';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

And here’s my `www.example.com` configuration:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/after/*;
```

Everything works, HTTP redirects to HTTPS, and www redirects to non-www, but I’d like to do the opposite and redirect non-www to www. I added

```
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
```

to `example.com` and commented it out in `www.example.com` configuration to remove the loop, but it didn’t work:

```
www.example.com redirected you too many times.
```

I also tried to copy the contents of non-www configuration to www configuration, and listen to 443 there, but it was still redirecting endlessly. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works, HTTP redirects to HTTPS, and www redirects to non-www, but I’d like to do the opposite and redirect non-www to www.

As per [Force WWW behind an AWS EC2 Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242609/force-www-behind-an-aws-ec2-load-balancer/45514132#45514132), this happens because the default `forge-conf/example.com/before/redirect.conf`, which you never mention, but which must still be included, must still contain a `server` definition with `server_name www.example.com` and `return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;`, hence, when you try to do the opposite `redirect` within your own configuration, together with the default configuration that must still be left about, you create a full redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach:

**www.example.com** should look like

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/120143/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/120143/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '[...]';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/after/*;
```

**example.com** should look like

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

Comment: Same thing: `domain redirected you too many times`. If I follow www domain, I get redirected to the non-www one for some reason; I did restart Nginx.

Comment: Did you clean your browser cache? @Banandrew

Comment: Yes. Just tried it in a different browser that’s completely cleaned, same error there.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the config, by switch adding www to non-www in those config file. Also, because you are using Lets Encrypt for SSL, you probably need to switch config for `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` to point to correct files,

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/120143/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/120143/server.key;
```

Just restart your computer to refresh network cache.

Comment: I did it, doesn’t work. There were no certificate/key under `/etc/nginx/ssl` for the www version, I tried copying them and changing the path in the corresponding configuration, but it also didn’t help.

Comment: you don't copy it, but create it with encrypt `./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com -d www.example.com`